# Forked Grails VM exited with error while running test-app

Tags: grails

I try to come up with a fresh new Grails application. I decided to use Grails 2.5.0 with JDK7 on windows 8. To get a start I do a

```
grails create-app test
cd test
grails create-domain-class test.Book
```

modify the domain class to

```
package test

class Book {

    String  title
    BigDecimal  price
    static constraints = {
      title()
      price()
    }
}
```

do a

```
grails refresh-dependencies
grails generate-all test.Book
```

and then

```
grails test-app
```

the test outputs some errors - that's ok, but the test run stops with an error message:

```
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

So, I thought it might be a problem with Grails 2.5.0 and I switched to Grails 2.4.5. Same problem.

Even `grails run-app --stacktrace` yields no stacktrace...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the tests reports produced in the target directory?

Comment: @GraemeRocher: test reports are produced (xml+html). If I try to use  spock-reports (https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports) - those extra reports are not generated.